# Combine two bash scripts dynamically to display CPU and Memory

Tags: bash, shell

I have one script which print different logs with date in continuous.

```
./script1

Date Log
Date Log
Date Log ...
```

I have an other one, prustat, which print %CPU, and %mem ...

```
./prustat

%CPU %mem
1.2 3
```

I would like to combine both to have :

```
Date Log
%CPU %mem
1.2 3
Date Log
%CPU %mem
1.2 3
```

...

in order to have the CPU consumption and memory for each log.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It kind of looks like you want

```
./script1.sh | 
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    ./script2.sh
done
```

But there must be something you're not telling us about the contents of scripts 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

You could either put `./prustat` inside `script1` (last line) or you can call them both like this :

```
./script1; ./prustat
```

Comment: Yeah but ./script1 prints in continue

Comment: Can you put ./prustat inside the loop in script1?

Answer (score 0):

Well if it is running continuously unsure why you would want them to both run together?

you could try:

```
./script1.sh& ./script2.sh
```

This would call the script1 and fork it as a back ground job then call script2.sh

now you will get back your command prompt

you can do

fg%1 to get back script1.sh

Unsure why you would want to do something like this though..

Doing above would mean if you relaunch it again the previous job is still running in the background and you would get a secondary job running -

in short you should incorporate both scripts into one and call script2 when needed within script1 and let script1 run continuously.

This would be painful..

So an alternative would be:

```
timeout 1 ./script1.sh; ./script2.sh
```

This would execute script1 and timeout after 1 second then run script2

Answer (score 0):

This should combine both scripts outputs.

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'rm /tmp/z[12]' 0
./script1 > /tmp/z1 &
./prustat > /tmp/z2 &
tail -qfc +1 /tmp/z[12]
```

There is however no synchronization so depending on each script output frequency, the order not might be what you expect.

*Edit: it is unclear is both scripts provide a continuous output or just the first one. My answer assumes both do.*